# Could not display not found information using conditional syntax inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a searching system where user search by typing the place. If the place does not match, it should show not found and if place matches, it should show the place detail. What I did is

**code**

```
render() {
        var margin = { marginTop : '13em' };
        if (this.state.place){
        let location = _.map(this.state.place, (place,id) => {
            return(
                    <Room key={id}
                    slug={place.slug}
                    place={place.place}
                    city={place.city}
                    gallery={place.gallery}
                    property={place.property}/>
                )
            console.log('location',location);
        });
        let gallery = _.map(this.state.place, (place,id) => {
            console.log('place',place.gallery);
            _.map(place.gallery, (image,id) => {
                return(
                        <img src={image.image} class="img-fluid" />
                    )
            });
        });
        let noLocation = () => {
          return(
            <div className="noroom">There is no room</div>
          );
          console.log('nolocation');
        };

        return(
            <div className = "container">
                <div className="content text-align-center">
                    <div className="row text-xs-center">
                        <div className="middle-text"  style={margin}>
                            <h1 className="welcome"><span>Common Rental Space</span></h1>
                            <p className="appSubtitle">facilitates your search for rental space all over Nepal</p>
                            <button ref="test" className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.handleClick}>Search Space</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mySearch" className="overlay"  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
                  <button className="btn closebtn" onClick={this.handleClick}>x</button>
                  <div className="overlay-content">
                        <SearchInput ref="searchInput" className="search-input" onChange={this.searchUpdated} />
                         <div className="container searchList">
                             { this.state.place > 1 ? {location} : {noLocation} }
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
    }
}
```

What might be the error? The syntax is `{ condition ? true : false }`

When I do `{this.state.place >1 ? { location } : {noLocation} }` I get an error

**app.js:1030 Uncaught Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.1.1.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a `<tbody>` when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>, <p>, or <a>` or using non-SVG elements in an `<svg>` parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.**

When I do `this.state.place >1?{location}:{noLocation}`i get `this.state.place >1 ? result`, and if place does not match the page shows `this.state.place >1 ? :.`

Comment: can you tell us what the error says? anything in the console?

Comment: If I type the place that is not in the server I get ? : in the page instead of there is no room.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noLocation` appears to be a method, but you aren't actually calling the method anywhere - so you are basically telling reaction to render the function itself, not the result of the method.

If it must be a method, try, noting the extra ():

```
{ this.state.place.length >=1 ? location : noLocation() }
```

Comment: I get only there is no room text in the page even when I type the place that matches to the server

Comment: You're experiencing many different problems - probably best to break them down in to diff questions with only the bit that is not working. In your case though - it seems like it should be `this.state.place >= 1`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what do you mean to say by different problem?

Comment: Well the first problem was related to having a function within an expression (instead of the result of the function), then syntax errors because you were using {} within {}, now we are looking at some kind of logic error. It's fine, but it becomes a lot of working stepping someone through each problem they are having

Comment: Ok i will try to fix it as this.state.place >= 1 is also not working for me.Thanks

Comment: Sorry i missed the cute length property.Its working now using .length. :)

Comment: Excellent - well done on working through it. If this answer has helped you with your question, please mark it correct for future SO users